# PowerApps - How can I reference the Created By SharePoint field in the form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, spfield, powerapps-forms, reference

I am modifying a SharePoint form in PowerApps, and I'm trying to populate a text field based on whether or not the Created By field (from SharePoint) is populated.  Essentially I'm trying to set a field upon submission from a button i created.  It doesn't populate the form in SP, even though it works in preview mode.  So is there a way I can have a text label display "Submitted" if Created By contains a value?  If it doesn't, it can just be blank.  Created By gets populated upon submission, so I'm trying to reference it.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to show the value in text label on "view" or "edit" list form?

Comment: The text label won't be visible.  I'm going to use it as a reference to hide certain fields after initial submission.  So when the form is first created, don't want that individual to see certain fields, and other labels beneath their relevant fields.  Once they submit, an email gets sent (power automate) to an approver.  When they click the Link to Item url in the body of the email, I want them to see all of it.  So my idea was to have a text label that displays "Submitted" (or any arbitrary text) if Created By contains a value.  B/c then I can hide other fields/labels based on Created By

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting "Text" property of label control to in this format:

```
If(IsBlankOrError(ThisItem.'Created By'.Email), "", "Submitted")
```

OR

```
If(IsBlank(ThisItem.'Created By'.Email), "", "Submitted")
```

Comment: Thank you, Ganesh!  I used the 2nd formula.  Seems to be working correctly now.